# FFMpeg for Android not working on Genymotion emulator

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, genymotion

We are able to run and compress a video using ffmpeg on a real Android device, but when we try to use it on Genymotion emulator, it gives some errors and doesnt work.

We are doing chmod on /system/bin folder, and copying it do /data/data/app.

This is what we see trying to do only the -version command on logcat after requesting errors on cmd:

[Ljava.lang.String;@52a20e6c/data/data/com.video.myapp/ffmpeg[1]: syntax error: '�4�' unexpected

[/data/data/com.video.myapp/ffmpeg, -version]

Do you know what could be it?

Comment: How are you invoking ffmpeg?

Comment: Could you provide us with a sample, or at least the output of "ffmpeg -i videofile.ext"? which version of Genymotion is it? which version of Android have you tried?

Comment: Are you able to get any solution?